# ZendX JQuery DatePicker viewHelper

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, datepicker, zend-form-element, zendx

I built a form using the element DatePicker

```
$datefile= new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker('df');
```

when I try to render this field in the view using

```
<?= $this->form->df->renderViewHelper(); ?>
```

like I render normal  Zend_Form_Element_Text('xx')

```
    <?= $this->form->xx->renderViewHelper(); ?>
```

I get this error:

```
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:

Message: Decorator by name ViewHelper does not exist
```

I don't just echo the form using

```
echo $this->form
```

I use my own layout for the FORM..

Cant figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use this

```
<?= $this->form->df->renderUiWidgetElement(); ?>
```